# How to use a bash profile function to connect remotely and access the remote terminal

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-desktop, .bash-profile

I want to write a `bash function` locally (on MacOS), so when I run this function the first command is to get connected to an ubuntu Remote Desktop through `ssh`.

In a nutshell:

```
    my_func () {
    ssh blah blah blah;
    echo $VARIABLE;
}
```

The desired output is sth like `/home/ubuntu/path/to/directory`, but I get nothing. So I have the impression that `my_func` works only locally.

P.S. The environment variable `$VARIABLE` is set in the `~/.bashrc` in the remote Desktop.

Comment: Where does `$VARIABLE` get set?  Also the `;`'s are unnecessary, bash treats new lines as command separators.  Why do you think it would work remotely?

Comment: @Jesse_b Edited.

Comment: So you want it to SSH to the remote machine and then execute the command: `echo $VARIABLE`?

Comment: @Jesse_b Exactly (basically, I want to do other things, but this is an important step to achieve the next steps).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should work:

```
my_func () {
    ssh user@ip echo '$VARIABLE'
}
```

or if you have more commands you can do:

```
my_func () {
    ssh user@ip <<'EOF'
    echo $VARIABLE
    command2
    command3
EOF
}
```

You could also (my favorite for executing a lot of commands) put your commands in another file and do this:

```
my_func () {
    SOURCE_FILE='/path/to/file'
    cat "$SOURCE_FILE" | ssh user@ip
}
```

Comment: I think you need to escape the variable like this: `"\$VARIABLE"` or use single quotes like this `'$VARIABLE'`.

Comment: @Jesse_b  Unforunately, none of these works. I manage to get connected to the remote terminal, but then when I echo, nothing happens.

Comment: @gogators Thanks! You're right, the local machine was trying to expand the variable before sending it to the remote machine.